# How to save an enumeration into ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

Turns out that WinRT's ability to save settings throws an exception when you try to store an enumeration value. MSDN says on the page ["Accessing app data with the Windows Runtime"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464917.aspx) that only ["Runtime Data Types"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br205768.aspx) are supported.

So, how do you save an enum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a really strange behavior. But easy to solve.

First you need some type of parse routine like this:

```
T ParseEnum<T>(object value)
{
    if (value == null)
        return default(T);
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value.ToString());
}
```

Note: the default value of an ENUM is always its 0 value member.

Then you can interact with it like this:

```
var _Settings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values;

// write
_Settings["Color"] = MyColors.Red.ToString()

// read
return ParseEnum<MyColors>(_Settings["Color"]);
```

Basically, we're just transforming it to a string.

Comment: Why not convert the enumerator to an integer type instead?  (`ToString()` seems like overkill here and won't work e.g. in C++ projects.)

Comment: You could convert it to an integer. But only String is 100% reliable since you can choose byte and long as the backend types of a enum, too. But if you know your type, you can convert it to whatever you want. If you do cast it to a direct source, you can probably benefit on performance, too - if that matters on something this trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to achieve that goal by utilize underlying type of enum to serialize value

```
public void Write<T>(string key, T value)
{
    var settings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

    if (typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().IsEnum)
    {
        settings.Values[key] = Convert.ChangeType(value, Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)));
        return;
    }

    settings.Values[key] = value;
}

public bool TryRead<T>(string key, out T value)
{
    var settings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

    object tmpValue;
    if (settings.Values.TryGetValue(key, out tmpValue))
    {
        if (tmpValue == null)
        {
            value = default(T);
            return true;
        }

        if (typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().IsEnum)
        {
            value = (T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(T), tmpValue);
            return true;
        }

        if (tmpValue is T)
        {
            value = (T) tmpValue;
            return true;
        }
    }

    value = default(T);
    return false;
}
```

Usage sample

```
// write
Write("Color", MyColors);

// read
MyColor value;
TryRead<MyColor>("Color", out value)
```